# Having trouble with Generics in this .NET code 

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i'm trying to make a mixed collection of Types. I know the types at the start.. but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to make the collection, etc.

eg.

```
....
// I leave the typo there, for embarrassment :(
Initialize(new []{ typeof(Cat), typeof(Dog), typeof(JohnSkeet) }); 
...

public Foo Initialize(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
   // for each type, set up the inmemory storage.
   foreach(var type in types)
   {
       // ????
       // Create an empty list, which will only contain this 'type'
       // I'm guessing, an IDictionary<type, ICollection<type>>().. thingy ?
   }
}

public ICollection<Type> SomeTypeData(Type type)
{
    // Return the collection, for this type.
}
```

Does this mane sense? Is this possible?

Comment: `typeof(JohnSkeet)` -> `TheresNoHInJonSkeetException`

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest... although I very much doubt that it'll be feasible without reflection.

Comment: @Jon Sorry for getting the name wrong, Jon (it's after midnight down under ... ). Hmm. I'm trying to make an Generic InMemory Object Context. I've made concrete InMemory contexts before, but i'm trying to see if i can abstract this just a wee bit ...

Comment: @Jon, it's clear to me, he wants to create a list containing you and your clones ;)

Comment: .. and those in memory contexts are just a simple class that has lots of IList's .. eg. IList<Cat> cats; IList<Cat> uncommitedCats; etc... So i was just seeing if i could have this handled using generics and via passing in a constructor of the types which I'll be using...

Comment: But where are you populating the *contents* of the collections?  i.e.  If the dictionary/list is a list of dog/cat/skeet, where do the dogs, cats, and Skeets come from in your code?

Comment: @Kirk Woll through the method `SomeTypeData(Type)`. I'm thinking my code might do this... `var cats = inMemoryContext.SomeTypeData(typeof(Cat)); if (cats != null) { cats.Add(new Cat("purrrrr")); }` sorta thing.. ?

Comment: In that case, since your calling code would already know that the collection returned should be of type `List<Cat>`, you could change the signature of `SomeTypeData(Type)` to be `SomeTypeData<T>()`.  My answer demonstrates both a generic and non-generic approach for the `SomeTypeData` method.  You might still want to have both, though, since there might be situations where you can't use the generic version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to create some kind of instance repository; a class that stores a list of instances of a given type.

Here's an example implementation.  I've included both a generic and non-generic version of the SomeTypeData method:

```
public class InstanceRepository
{
    private IDictionary<Type, ICollection> _Instances = new Dictionary<Type, ICollection>();

    public ICollection SomeTypeData(Type type)
    {
        ICollection instanceList;
        if (!_Instances.TryGetValue(type, out instanceList))
        {
            // this type does not exist in our dictionary, so let's create a new empty list

            // we could do this:
            //instanceList = new List<object>();

            // but let's use reflection to make a more type-specific List<T> instance:
            instanceList = (ICollection)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));

            // now add it to the dictionary
            _Instances.Add(type, instanceList);
        }
        // Return the collection, for this type.
        return instanceList;
    }

    public IList<T> SomeTypeData<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ICollection instanceList;
        if (!_Instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out instanceList))
        {
            instanceList = new List<T>();
            _Instances.Add(type, instanceList);
        }
        // here we are assuming that all of the lists in our dictionary implement IList<T>.
        // This is a pretty safe assumption, since the dictionary is private and we know that
        // this class always creates List<T> objects to put into the dictionary.
        return (IList<T>)instanceList;
    }
}
```

Below is a usage example:

Generic:

```
        InstanceRepository repository = new InstanceRepository();

        var listOfCats = repository.SomeTypeData<Cat>();

        listOfCats.Add(new Cat());

        Cat firstCat = listOfCats[0];

        Console.WriteLine(listOfCats.GetType().FullName);
```

Non-Generic:

```
        InstanceRepository repository = new InstanceRepository();

        var listOfCats = (IList<Cat>)repository.SomeTypeData(typeof(Cat));

        listOfCats.Add(new Cat());

        Cat firstCat = listOfCats[0];

        Console.WriteLine(listOfCats.GetType().FullName);
```

Comment: yeah, i'm doing an instance repository (i suppose). i was calling it an inmemory repo, cause it had list instances in memory :P

Answer (score 6):

Okay, now that I think I know what you want, it would look something like this:

```
// This can't really be *properly* statically typed
private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> typeMap = new 
    Dictionary<Type, object>();

public Foo Initialize(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
   Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);
   foreach(var type in types)
   {
       // MakeGenericType is really badly named
       Type constructedListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(type);
       typeMap[type] = Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
   }
}

// We can't express this particularly safely either,
// although we *could* return the non-generic IList
public object SomeTypeData(Type type)
{
    return typeMap[type];
}

// This *is* statically typed, although we need to cast inside
public IList<T> SomeTypeData<T>()
{
    return (IList<T>) typeMap[typeof(T)];
}
```

See [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/mapping-from-a-type-to-an-instance-of-that-type.aspx) for a similar example.

Note that basically you're trying to represent something which generics simply can't handle, in terms of the internal dictionary type... and the first form of `SomeTypeData` can't be statically typed either... because that means knowing the type at *compile time* when we'll only actually be given it at *execution time*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand you're question, but if you already have an `IEnumerable<Type>` which contains an enumeration of Type objects, then why not just use that to initialize some type of Collection (such as `List<Type>`)?

```
    public ICollection<Type> Initialize(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        ICollection<Type> collection = new List<Type>(types);

        return collection;
    }
```

Comment: because i actually want strongly typed lists. not a list _of_ types... This is why i'm thinking i might need an IDictionary<type, IList<type>> , if that is possible?

Comment: No, that's not really it. Given an enumerable of types, he wants to create collections containing objects of T, where typeof(T) == type. Follow? So given `new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(Foo) }`, he wants `ICollection<string>, ICollection<int>, ICollection<Foo>`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like

```
_dict[typeof(Cat)]=new List<Cat>();
_dict[typeof(Dog)]=new List<Dog>();
```

only programatically based on given types?

Something like this should work:

```
public void Initialize(IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    foreach(var type in types)
    {
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1").MakeGenericType(type));
        _cache[type] = list;
    }
}

public ICollection<T> Get<T>()
{
    object list;
    if (_cache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out list)
    {
       return list as ICollection<T>;
    }
    else
    {
       ...
    }
}

var cats = Get<Cat>();
```